# Switching to Lightning- does this change ANYTHING for classic?

Tags: lightning

Wasn't quite sure how to word this. I'm looking to change to Lightning, and I have it enabled on our org's sandbox, and would like to try it in the "real world." I've already created new profiles and removed the lightning ability from them, and assigned those to all the other users. Meaning I would be the *only* one with it enabled. That being said, if I do go through and enable it, as long as those other users remain on classic, is there ANYTHING that could change for them or in the "background" somehow screwing something up? The goal here is to test it myself for a few weeks doing my daily routine, then show it to our sales staff, train them, and general roll-out. We're *fairly* small btw, only about 12 users including myself, so far.

TL;DR - As long as all other users other than myself are removed from the "lightning user" checkbox, and are kept on classic, will they experience ANY changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to be honest it actually depends very heavily in your org and the kind of customizations it has.

My suggestion is that you go to the **[migration assistant](https://admin.salesforce.com/migration-assistant-your-path-into-the-lightning-experience)** and follow the steps. It will guide you through the process and inform you if it finds any custom things that might be an issue, like JS buttons for example.

In case you want to read some more before going to the assistant, I recommend the **[trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/lex_admin_migration)** related to lightning migration. They are pretty extensive but contain a lot of useful information. Furthermore, I found **[this](https://admin.salesforce.com/migrating-lightning-experience-classic)** article quite good too.

Comment: Thanks for that! I have gone through the migration assistant, I've gotten my readiness report and read through it. I guess I was just looking for more of a confirmation from a "person" rather than a guide that I can't ask something to/of. I've also done the trailhead modules as well, and they were really helpful. There was some old Pardot stuff, but we don't use that for marketing anymore. It's killing me not having it enabled in prod. so I can use it every day. With this confirmation though, I think I'll enable for myself after Christmas.

Comment: @DevinPearman I actually read wrong your question, my bad! :) Don't forget to mark whichever answer you found most helpful!

Answer (score 2):

There's no changes that would be visible to users in Classic. Lightning users may be missing some elements (such as the unsupported JavaScript buttons), but those limitations are on Lightning, not Classic.

Comment: Thank you! As I mentioned in my other comment, I was definitely looking for a confirmation from an actual person, other than just reading through that readiness report. I'll plan on enabling then for myself just after Christmas.